# Utilizar coluna oid no PostgreSQL como chave primária é correto?

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, chave-primária

O PostgreSQL cria por padrão a coluna OIDs (identificadores de objeto), pode-se obter ele fazendo.

```
 select oid, * from table
```

Problema que tenho uma tabela que não possui chave primária, e quero mapear ela no Fluent nHibernate (C#).

É melhor usar o `oid` como chave primária ou criar uma chave composta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`oid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) é uma chave primária. A questão é se deve deixá-la como PK ou usar uma outra que faz ela deixar de ser usada como PK.

Não é simples cravar isso, mas você obviamente pode fazê-lo. Ele tem algumas condições que indicam o seu uso, mas não todas. Existem situações que não tem problema algum em usá-la, pode ser que você só precisa de uma chave primária por uma questão técnica, ou seja, sua aplicação não se importa com ela.

Minha opinião é [a mesma que achei na lista de discussão do produto](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/m13FdJf-000AXVC%40druid.net), evite usá-lo, e se usar tenha certeza que entende todas implicações do seu uso. Eu prefiro ter total controle sobre a chave primária. Nunca usei `oid`. Elas tem algumas desvantagens e poucas vantagens, nada grave, mas acho que é suficiente pra mim. Prefiro usar um serial mesmo.

- Não tem integridade referencial,
- transferir valores externamente pode ser uma complicação enorme, ela não é GUID,
- é fora do padrão, até mesmo ferramentas específicas do PostgreSQL a ignora,
- você não tem controle sobre ele,
- a pergunta já mostra que o uso do `*` não inclui ela.

Se precisa de uma chave composta então tem que usá-la, `oid` não é alternativa para isto.