# Como é gerado o GUID (Identificador Único Global)?

Tags: c#, .net, independente-de-linguagem, guid

O [Identificador Único Global](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%9Anico_Global) é gerado de forma que nenhum outro será gerado igual, ou quase nunca terá o mesmo número.

```
 var unique = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

`Resultado: 440cdeee-5b8a-462a-96fd-20b24bd82f55`

- Como isso é possível?
- Existe alguma fórmula matemática por trás? Se sim, como funciona?

Comment: Espero por uma resposta que explique como isso é possível quando estamos offline também.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza creio que seja uma formula matemática muito bem trabalhada! No aguardo de uma resposta aqui :)

Comment: Oxente, -1 ? Por que ? tava +7 agora .6 ?

Comment: @MagicHat Percebi aqui também! Vai saber :)

Comment: @Marconi acho que as criticas fortalecem, mas quando apontado o ponto, assim num vale de nada...

Comment: @MagicHat vdd, até pra melhorarmos!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Como isso é possível?

Números grandes (2 elevado a 128) possuem capacidade considerada quase infinita.

Não há garantias que o GUID seja único sempre. Até existem versões que garantem, mas pode usar a versão que não garante. Mesmo não garantindo, a [possibilidade de haver colisão é muito pequena, desprezível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40525/101).

> Existe alguma formula matemática por trás, como funciona?

[De acordo com a Wikipedia o formato do UUID (o mesmo que GUID usado pela Microsoft) é](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier):

```
123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-Mxxx-Nxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

- 4-byte (8 dígitos em representação hexadecimal) parte menos significante do horário da geração do UUID.
- 2-byte (4 dígitos em representação hexadecimal) parte média significante do horário da geração do UUID.
- 2-byte (4 dígitos em representação hexadecimal) versão do UUID seguido de parte mais significante do horário da geração do UUID.
- 2-byte separados em 2 campos (no total 4 dígitos em representação hexadecimal) sequência de resolução do *clock*, alta no primeiro campo e baixa no segundo, com multiplexação nos primeiros bits para complementar a versão.
- 6-bytes (12 dígitos em representação hexadecimal) nó adotado.

Note que isso é uma representação visual para humanos. Você não precisa armazenar ou transmitir estes 36 caracteres. Basta gerar um número de 128 bits, portanto no computador ele só precisa ocupar 16 bytes.

## Versões

Esses dados são preenchidos de formas diferentes dependendo da versão. A implementação do UUID de cada biblioteca pode fazer da forma que melhor convier, inclusive variando de acordo com o uso. Não precisa preencher exatamente como foi descrito acima, só precisa seguir o padrão de geração de acordo com a especificação da versão escolhida.

- Uma das versões mais usadas é a 1, onde o preenchimento é o horário e o *MAC address* daquela máquina, assim garante-se a unicidade.

  Existem algumas formas para garantir que não seja gerado dois tempos iguais se o relógio da máquina não possuir muita resolução. O horário tem que ser único na máquina. E unicidade total se dá por identificar em qual máquina ele foi gerado, partindo do princípio que clonar *MAC address* não é feito, já que esta não é uma operação normal. Vou omitir os detalhes.
- A versão 2 não costuma ser usada porque envolve protocolo de segurança não divulgado.
- As versões 3 e 5 usa um [*hashing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184019/101) de um [*namespace*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/140268/101). A unicidade é obtida baseando-se em um nome que já é único. Este nome pode ser um [URL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43224/101) (quando o programador inexperiente com isso vê um URL em um arquivo acha que está acessando aquele endereço, mas é só um *namespace* único) ou um [identificador de objeto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier) que tem uma lógica própria de criar unicidade. Essa forma é vantajosa porque pode ser repetível, ou seja, o mesmo nome gera o mesmo UUID.

  A versão 3 usa MD5 e a versão 5 usa SHA1, bem melhor, porém mais "pesada".

  [Exemplo](https://github.com/tcjennings/LUA-RFC-4122-UUID-Generator/blob/master/uuid5.lua).
- A versão 4 usa um número gerado aleatoriamente. Esta forma pode ser usada em qualquer máquina, mesmo na ausência de um *MAC address* ou um *clock* razoável. Ela pode ter colisões, mas por ter uma resolução alta é *improvável* que ocorra. Idealmente deveria ser um número verdadeiramente aleatório, mas um pseudoaleatório é aceito.

  [Exemplo](https://github.com/tcjennings/LUA-RFC-4122-UUID-Generator/blob/master/uuid4.lua).

Obviamente que cada versão tem especificado como esses dados são distribuídos naqueles campos indicados acima e o algoritmo será diferente de acordo com a versão, mas basicamente é obter os números necessários de acordo com a especificação. Isto normalmente é uma simples chamada à API do sistema operacional e montar no formato especificado.

> Como isso é possível quando estamos offline?

Ele foi criado para ser *offline* mesmo. Ele não tem que estar em rede ligada para funcionar. Ele não o busca em outro lugar.

Talvez a confusão venha porque ele é usado como chave primária em banco de dados, imagino que exista a ideia de que o cliente pede para o servidor um número global único, mas na verdade o cliente gera por conta própria. Inclusive tem a vantagem de [poder gerar o registro todo sem consultar o banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21907/101). Geralmente quando usamos um `ID` sequencial tem que perguntar para o servidor qual é ele depois do `insert` ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166240/101)).

Gera sozinho até porque é usado em várias coisas que só diz respeito à máquina mesmo.

Se prestar atenção nos *internals* muita coisa do sistema operacional do que você acessa com um nome bonitinho, esse nome é só descritivo, o seu nome de identidade mesmo é um GUID. Se usasse o nome poderia ter colisões de nome e uma tradução do nome faria o objeto ser outro, o GUID é canônico.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Esse "trem" como diz aqui em minas é mais complexo do que eu imagina. :)

Comment: @Marconi depende do ponto de vista, eu acho até simples demais :)

Comment: O pessoal da Microsoft que já deixa mastigado pra gente, desenvolver algo do tipo creio que iria dá trabalho @bigown!

Comment: @Marconi botei exemplos em Lua que o algoritmo na verdade é bem simples e pequeno. Você verá que é mais complicado explicar do que fazer :D

Comment: Muito interessante. Nunca tinha pesquisado sobre como eles são gerados.

Answer (score 11):

**1 - "Sei que o Indentificador Único Global é gerado de forma que nem um outro será igual."**

No próprio link que colocas diz: "Apesar de cada GUID gerado **não possuir nenhuma garantia de ser único**, o número total de chaves únicas (2^128 ou -3.4×10^38) é tão grande, que a probabilidade de o mesmo número ser gerado duas vezes é muito pequena. Por exemplo, considerando que o universo observável contém 5×10^22 estrelas, cada estrela poderia ter ~6.8×10^15 de GUIDs próprios."

**2 - "Existe alguma fórmula matemática por trás, como funciona?"**

Sim, existe um padrão e algumas versões sendo:

Em sua representação textual canônica, os dezesseis octetos de um UUID são representados por 32 dígitos minúsculos hexadecimais (base 16), exibidos em cinco grupos separados por hifens, na forma 8-4-4-4-12 para um total de 36 caracteres (32 caracteres alfanuméricos e quatro hifens). Por exemplo:

```
123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
```

A string de formato canónico 8-4-4-4-12 é baseada no "[layout de registro](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1.2)" para os 16 bytes do UUID:

- Um inteiro de 4 bytes (8 dígitos hexadecimais) "time_low" dando os
  baixos 32 bits do tempo.
- Um número inteiro "time_mid" de 2 bytes (4 dígitos hexadecimais) dando ao meio 16 bits do tempo.
- Um  campo "time_hi_and_version" de 2 bytes (4 dígitos hexadecimais), com a "versão" de 4 bits nos bits mais significativos, seguidos pelos 12 bits mais altos do tempo.
- Dois campos de 1 byte (totalizando 4 dígitos hexadecimais) chamados "clock_seq_hi_res" e "clock_seq_lo", com a "variante" multiplexada nos mais significativos 1 a 3 bits de clock_seq_hi_res.
- Seis bytes (12 dígitos hexadecimais) com o "nó" de 48 bits.

[Fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

**Algoritmo básico**

O seguinte algoritmo é simples, correto e ineficiente:

- Obter um bloqueio global do sistema.
- De um armazenamento estável compartilhado do sistema (por exemplo, um arquivo), leia o estado do gerador UUID: os valores do timestamp, sequência de relógio, e ID de nó usados ​​para gerar o último UUID.
- Obter a hora atual como uma contagem de 60 bits de intervalos de 100 nanossegundos desde 00:00:00.00, 15 de outubro de 1582.
- Obter o ID do nó atual.
- Se o estado não estiver disponível (por exemplo, inexistente ou corrompido), ou o ID do nó salvo é diferente do ID do nó atual, gerar um valor de sequência de clock aleatório.
- Se o estado estiver disponível, mas o timestamp salvo é mais tarde do que
  o carimbo de data/hora atual, incrementar o valor da sequência de clock.
- Salvar o estado (timestamp atual, sequência do relógio e ID do nó) de volta para o valor estável armazenado.
- Solte o bloqueio global.
- Formate um UUID a partir do timestamp atual, sequência de clock e nó ID de acordo com as etapas da [Seção 4.2.2.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.2.1)

Esse é o padrão básico no caso específico da pergunta: "**GUID**" é uma variante do **UUID** implementado pela Microsoft que utiliza a [versão 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.2.2) do UUID.

Justamente por estar implementado no sistema operacional é que é possível ser gerado `off-line` como questionado nos comentários.

Demais informações: [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122)

Comment: Gostei bastante aqui também @MagicHat :)

Comment: Show... Uma boa pergunta...

Answer (score 9):

Há um artigo descrevendo como GUIDs são geradas (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823) e também o porque de o substring de um Guid não ser garantido de ser único.

Basicamente um GUID é gerado usado a combinação de:

**MAC adrress da máquina utilizada pra gerar o GUID -** GUIDs gerados em diferentes máquinas são únicas, a não ser que o MAC seja reutilizado.

**Timestamp -** então os GUIDs gerados em horário diferente na mesma máquina são diferentes.

**Extra "bits unificadores de emergência"** - são utilizados para garantir que os GUIDs gerados praticamente no mesmo tempo e na mesma máquina sejam únicos.

**Identificador para o algoritimo -** GUIDs gerados por diferentes algorítimos são únicos.

Entretanto, esse é apenas um algoritimo em particular utilizado para gerar GUID.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888254/how-does-c-sharp-generate-guids