# Para que serve e por que usar o GuidAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net, atributos, guid

Sei que o GUID é um identificador 'único', mas não vejo o por que da sua aplicação do atributo, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
[GuidAttribute("C281C7F1-4AA9-3517-961A-463CFED57E75")]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[CLSCompliant(false)]
[TypeLibImportClassAttribute(typeof(System.Threading.Thread))]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
public interface _Thread {#
 if !FEATURE_CORECLR
 void GetTypeInfoCount(out uint pcTInfo);

 void GetTypeInfo(uint iTInfo, uint lcid, IntPtr ppTInfo);

 void GetIDsOfNames([In] ref Guid riid, IntPtr rgszNames, uint cNames, uint lcid, IntPtr rgDispId);

 void Invoke(uint dispIdMember, [In] ref Guid riid, uint lcid, short wFlags, IntPtr pDispParams, IntPtr pVarResult, IntPtr pExcepInfo, IntPtr puArgErr);#
 endif
}
```

<sub>[Fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.runtime.interopservices._thread(v=vs.110).aspx)</sub>

Para que serve e por que usar o `GuidAttribute`?

Comment: Um pouco mais: [Como é gerado o GUID (Identificador Único Global)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184538/como-%C3%A9-gerado-o-guid-identificador-%C3%9Anico-global)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O GUID é uma forma de criar um identificador (uma identidade) único estável (não vai mudar) para algum objeto de forma a não depender de nenhum mecanismo central que garanta a unicidade em mecanismos independentes.

Esse objeto deve ser único globalmente até mesmo se ele seja usado em máquinas diferentes que não "se conhecem".

Pensa em um domínio de internet. Ele é único. Como garante a unicidade? Tem um órgão central que não deixa existir dois nomes iguais. Ele pode até delegar isso para outros órgãos que tenha um padrão (CGI.br no Brasil pode cuidar de tudo que termina com .br).

Isso funciona bem porque é algo relacionado à internet, então só faz sentido ter algo em rede controlando a garantia de unicidade.

Se você tiver uma rede interna pode ter um servidor que garanta a unicidade. Quando cadastramos algo no banco de dados, ele pode garantir que dois objetos cadastrados tenha algum identificador único porque ele é um ponto central. Obviamente que essa base de dados não pode se mesclar naturalmente com uma base semelhante em outra rede já que esse outro banco pode ter gerado identificadores que já existe no primeiro banco de dados.

Se não tiver uma rede que permita controlar a unicidade e precise garanti-la no mundo todo, não importa a máquina que esse objeto seja colocado, o que fazer?

Cria-se um algoritmo que gera um identificador único que não possa ocorrer novamente em outra máquina em condições normais, assim se esse objeto for transmitido ou copiado para outra máquina não corre o risco de colisão.

Se for garantido que esse objeto não sairá da máquina podem ter algo que controle centralmente. Mesmo assim, nem sempre será um mecanismo tão adequado.

## Usando em código

Normalmente o tipo precisa de uma identificação única para uso com [Component Object Model (COM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model). Note que também usou o atributo `ComVisible`. Quando aquilo não for usado em COM o GUID não é necessário a não ser que sua aplicação crie essa demanda por motivos próprios.

Fica óbvio que esse tipo criado pela Microsoft pode estar em qualquer máquina do mundo que tenha um .NET instalado e ele precisa ser único, esta é a solução.

Você pode pensar que já que a Microsoft que fez, ela poderia garantir a unidade de forma mais simples. O problema é que qualquer programador pode criar um componente e poderia criar o mesmo identificador sem ela saber. Pior, dois ou mais programadores que não se conhecem poderiam criar o mesmo identificador. O GUID é o mecanismo que evita esses problemas.

Veja [como ele consegue ser único](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184538/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).