# Gerar número usando identity

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, delphi, modelagem, sql-server-2014

É possível gerar um número antes de gravar o registro no banco de dados? Uso campo `identity` do SQL Server 2014. Trabalho com Delphi Berlim.

Comment: Que tipo de numero, um numero aleatorio?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

De forma geral, não pode, pelo menos não pelo `IDENTITY` normal.

É possível usar algumas técnicas que ajudem nisso. Uma delas é gerar a inserção para obter o número e depois atualizar com os dados reais. Mas é bem problemático, precisa fazer a aplicação remover quando não precisa mais, pode criar buracos na numeração, tem que desligar restrições, enfim, não recomendo.

Outra é ter uma tabela onde você controla a numeração por conta própria e vai reservando ou soltando a reserva se a inserção não for efetivada. Não é simples, mas é uma solução melhor.

Claro que pode pegar o número após a inserção, que é a técnica mais comum e costuma funcionar bem na maioria das situações. Toda ideia do `IDENTITY` é essa mesmo, ter um controle centralizado próprio do banco de dados.

Outra forma é usar um UUID/GUID como chave primária, assim não precisa gerar nada no banco de dados, você já sabe de antemão qual o identificador sempre precisar ir ao banco de dados.

Deve interessar:

- [Para que serve e por que usar o GuidAttribute?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185195/101)
- [Qual a probablidade de se gerar um Guid Repetido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40525/101)
- [Devo utilizar GUID ou int como chave primária?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21907/101)
- [Como é gerado o GUID (Identificador Único Global)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184538/101)