# É viável migrar de long para Guid?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, guid

Usando WebApi, .NET Standard, C#, Entity Framework - CodeFirst

Os registros em `long` poderão estourar seus limites.

É viável mudar de `long` para `Guid` a chave primária com o banco povoado e serviço em execução?

Alguma outra alternativa, caso o `long` "estoure"?

Comment: Tem certeza que o `long` vai estourar? São 18 quintilhões, se você só armazenar ele e mais nada serão centenas de exabytes, ou milhões de HDDs do maior que existe só para esta tabela. E demoraria milhões de anos pra gravar tudo sem parar (vou considerar que consegue gravar um milhão de linhas por segundo, mas você não consegue em HDD, só em SSD que são bem menores, e não muito mais). É verdade que poderia levar só 1 ano se paralelizar em todos os SSDs, mas quero ver coordenar milhões deles tudo em um DB só. E algum motivo para usar GUID? Ou porque acha que ele é tão maior assim?

Comment: Use 2 longs, ué.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 7):

Tem certeza que o `long` vai estourar? São 18 quintilhões, se você só armazenar ele e mais nada serão centenas de exabytes ocupados, ou milhões de HDDs do maior que existe só para essa tabela. E demoraria milhões de anos pra gravar tudo sem parar (vou considerar que consegue gravar um milhão de linhas por segundo, mas você não consegue em HDD, só em SSD que são bem menores e precisaria mais). É verdade que poderia levar menos de 1 ano se paralelizar em todos os SSDs, mas quero ver coordenar milhões deles tudo em um DB só. Se tiver realmente vários computadores fazendo isso o GUID pode ser útil, mas só porque ele permite distribuição, não porque ele permite mais linhas e portanto mais `ID`s.

Por que acha que o GUID é tão maior assim? Ele pode aceitar números maiores, mas não necessariamente mais números diferentes. Você não consegue usar e imensa maioria dos GUIDs teóricos disponíveis. Veja como é composto um [GUID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184538/101). Ele não é sequencial ou consegue representar todos os números possíveis. A função dele não é ser maior, é permitir criar em máquinas diferentes em paralelo e se um dia essas informações se juntarem não dar colisão. Mas em muitos problemas onde há distribuição sequer as informações vão se juntar. Mas se seu problema é esse, nada tem a ver com `long` não ter capacidade.

A praticidade de ter algo tão grande é questionável e provavelmente está se preocupando com algo teórico inexistente. Claro, se o problema tivesse sido explicitado poderíamos falar algo mais específico.

Se realmente quiser insistir em usar algo maior, precisa ver o contexto, é possível que seja criado um formato específico que atenda a necessidade. Como será impossível usar todos os números tem que ter uma lógica de gerar os números.

Se quiser saber sobre a teoria de fazer sequencial você usuária dois `long`s e iria incrementando só o segundo, mantendo o primeiro sempre zerado, quando você usar todos os números do `long` você incrementa 1 no primeiro `long` e zera o segundo para começar tudo de novo nele. Tudo isso tem que ser feito manualmente ou por uma função ou *stored procedure*. Claro que se um dia isso for útil o banco de dados permitirá fazer automaticamente. Tem um motivo para ele não ter isso pronto.

Se precisar mudar um dia é tranquilo fazer, só o cuidado básico de mudar uma chave primária, afinal tem que mudar todas referências para a linha que agora tem outra chave. Claro que referências externas também precisam mudar. Se você não puder garantir que pode mudar todas, aí você terá que ter uma chave secundária com o `ID` antigo e detectar que está acessando pelo antigo e buscar por ele em vez do primário.

Comment: Maniero, acredito que então,  por exemplo,  o Instagram conseguiria armazenar todas suas postagens com um long, correto?

Comment: Com uma folga absurda. Se cada usuário postar bilhões de postagens ainda daria (ou seja, a pessoa passar a vida toda fazendo uma postagem sem parar e mais do que uma por segundo. E note que para administrar isto eles teriam um esquema de que não está tudo em uma tabela, na verdade provavelmente não usam um banco de dados tradicional, então toda essa conversa nem faz sentido.